# Display Facebook posts with cocoa

Tags: cocoa, facebook

I use Facebook connect in an app and I manage to get answers from facebook servers. I would like now to display those answers (simple facebook wall posts) like the facebook app.

In fact, I'm simply looking for the "facebook cell template" that I'll populate with the data I received.

This seems quite simple and I am sure a snippet of code will do that really well, but I can't find it as any searches with the keyword "facebook" give thousands of responses...

Comment: The problem is that we promote our app as a fully native one, so the HTML way won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to just use a `WebView` to display the content and use HTML/CSS to create the UI.